# Ionic platform add android error on Mac

Tags: android, ionic-framework

My English is not good.
 I have an issue when a try to add android platform using an ionic project
I get this:

```
Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1162:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
    at Object.exports.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:100:31)
    at runScriptViaChildProcessSpawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:188:23)
    at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:131:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:114:20
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
```